# How can i stop Android OS updare after tapping "INSTALL OVERNIGHT"

Tags: updates

So I'm running Android 6.0.1 and i don't want to update it, but when the notification popped up, i accidentally tapped "INSTALL OVERNIGHT", being 2AM to 5AM tomorrow. Is there anyway I could stop it? PLEASE HELP THANKS!

Comment: Would you please add what is your device brand ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an app or settings dedicated to handle OTA updates by visiting that app/settings one could easily choose to install now/schedule installation time/install later option.

This app/settings may vary brand to brand. So, there are all possible ways:

1. Open Settings-About Phone-Software Update.
2. Open Settings-Software Update.
3. Open dedicated app from app drawer( app name vary from brand to brand e.g. Updater in Xiaomi).

If in case homepage of the app doesn't show you any of the above written option. Please tap 3 dots on the upper right corner of the screen, there you will see options and choose accordingly.